https://graph.facebook.com/{your-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token} return empty data
I have the permissions public_profile, email, pages_read_engagement, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_insights, pages_show_list, read_insights, business_management. When I make a request to the API https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{your-user-id}/accounts?access_token={user-access-token} using a user ID and user access token, I sometimes get account data for some users, but for others, I receive empty data.
I encountered this issue before adding the business_management permission. After adding that permission, everything worked fine, but starting yesterday, users have been notifying me that they can't get account info.

were you able to solve it?

Unfortunately, not yet.
